# Unable to make remote connection to Ms Sql Server 2008 R2 in windows 2003 server

Tags: sql-server-2008

My sql server 2008 R2 is in ec2 machine whose environment is in windows 2003 server. I am trying to make remote connection to it from my local but couldn't. Even the telnet to 1433 port is also not working and to that port only sql server is listening.I can mstsc to server and connect locally using SSMS with no problem but remote connection doesn't work. I did/check the following steps:

a) Check remote connection option in sql server instance
b) Enabled the TCP/IP protocol from configuration manager
c) Off the firewall.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL 2008 has a utility called a "Surface Area Configuration Manager" that actually blocks the TCP port to external network interfaces, by default.   Check that out, and I'm betting it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I got the solution in other form. My ec2 machine was registered to a security policy in which 1433 was blocked. I need to change to other policy where this port was enabled, so now things working fine. :)